# request.getParameter String behaving as object

Tags: java, jsp, request

In my jsp I have an form where I use:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="${question.feedback}">
```

when I retrieve this value in my next servlet :

```
    String question= request.getParameter("question");
```

and I print it (just for test case)

```
System.out.println(question.toString());
```

I get the outprint of an question object with all his properties?

But because I call it with `request.getParameter` it's a String and I can't Cast it.  But of the outprint I would say it's an object.

I can't cast and I can't set it on the attribute in my JSP.  Is there a way to get this as an object in my servlet without putting it on the sessionscope.

Answer (score 1):

Your form will only submit the result of the call to `toString()` on the `feedback` property of the Question object.

If you want to get all the properties of the question from the form submission, then you should add a hidden field for each of the question properties, or find a way to transform a question to a String and vice-versa and use a single hidden field.

Or you should have the question stored somewhere on the server (in the session or in the database) and reload it from there.

Comment: "Your form will only submit the value of the feedback property of the Question object." but this property is submitted as an String to the next Servlet (feedback is an object on his own) and I do see all his properties also?  I just find this strange beacause if it whas an String it just would print the String

Comment: I clarified what it does. Refresh my answer.